# qtablewidget get new value after hitting "return"

Tags: python, pyqt

i have a qtablewidget which is updated asynchronosly.
now i am trying to set new values into the cells and read them back after hitting "enter/return". i have a function that catches the keypressevent and try to read the actual value from the cell that was changed.
the problem: i only get the previous value of the cell, not the new entered value, because the function is called when the enter key is pressed which is right before the cell is updated whith the new value. i cannot use `itemChanged().connect` because the table is also changed from another proccess and i only want to catch my own changes.

[old value (before editing value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9hub.png) 
[editing the value and hit enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yArB2.png)

function that is called after hitting  return:

```py
    def tableOnKeyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Return or event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Enter:
            for a in self.CmdtableWidget.selectedItems():
                print(a.text())     # prints only 789, not 123      
            QTableWidget.keyPressEvent(self.CmdtableWidget, event)      # pass on the keyPressEvent to the table
```

Comment: Move the base `keyPressEvent()` call at the *beginning* of the function (and outside the if). Also be aware that you should not overwrite event handlers like this, as it can lead to problems and bugs that are difficult to trace. Either subclass the table widget and properly override `keyPressEvent()` from there, or use an event filter.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didnt help.

Comment: Moving the super call would (and *should*) be sufficient, meaning that you probably did something else wrong, so please provide a [mre] as right now the code you provided is completely insufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have a solution/ workaround for that problem:
i had to change the current selected item. so the new value was applied and i could it read in the following.

after that:

```
self.CmdtableWidget.setCurrentItem(None)        # leave cell,otherwise we get no updated value to read
```

the value was applied to the cell